# MatLab: Efficient column vector processing

Tags: matlab

I want a column vector of random 5 and 1s (roughly equal number of each).  I can easily get a column vector of full of 5 and 0s by doing this:

`rc = 5*(rand(400,1)<0.5)`

I believe this is a MatLab style way of doing things.  However, I want to avoid having to do this:

```
    for y = 1 : length(rc)
       if rc(i) == 0
           rc(i) = 1;
       end         
    end
```

because 1) I have to iterate all over again 2) it's not 'MatLab like'.  Any ideas guys?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be then:

```
4* (rand(400, 1)< .5)+ 1
```

Comment: Thanks eat.  I left the long variable name in my code so just changed your post to a number instead.  Will accept answer when min time has passed.